# SnapSDK integration not working properly, Snapshot shows error: Something went wrong. Please try again later

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, snapchat

I followed all the steps from documentation and integrated `SnapSDK` in my iOS app but when I click the share button in my app it directs me to the `snapchat` but ends up with an error saying

> "Something went wrong please try again later".

```
 private func didTapSnapchatShare(cell: FeedTableViewCell){

    print("Share  button tapped ")
    cell.pauseVideoAndAnimation()
    showProgressIndicator(view: self.view)
    var watermarkStr = ""
    if let userName = cell.cellDataSource?.user?.name {
        watermarkStr = userName
    }
    let promptImage = cell.promptView?.asImage()
    cell.slPlayer?.exportVideo(withWatermarkString: watermarkStr, promptImage: promptImage, completionHandler: { status, filePathURL in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            hideProgressIndicator(view: self.view)


            if status, let filePathURL = filePathURL {

                let url = URL(string: "snapchat://")!
                if(!UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)){

                    if let reviewURL = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snapchat/id447188370?mt=8"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(reviewURL) {
                        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(reviewURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                        } else {
                            UIApplication.shared.openURL(reviewURL)
                        }

                        return
                    }
                }
                let video = SCSDKSnapVideo(videoUrl:filePathURL)

                let videoContent = SCSDKVideoSnapContent.init(snapVideo: video)
                let api = SCSDKSnapAPI(content: videoContent)
                api.startSnapping(completionHandler: { (error: Error?) in
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: SnapKit is an autolayout library...why is it tagged here?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am getting the same thing.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MicahMontoya hi you are required to add in your snapchat ID in the development portal as a demo/tester user, in order to make video sharing work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your file path url is correct or not this happens when we are not using the correct file path sdk will not be able to find the image.